# ld: framework not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xctest

```
ld: framework not found QorumLogs for architecture x86_64  
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm getting this in my test files which used to work for months now. This is my header in the file:

```
import XCTest
import QorumLogs
@testable import MyAppName
```

The only thing I've changed recently is, update cocoapods, (QorumLogs is a pod), then installed Smooch.io pod, then for the first time added objective-c bridging header, created some Obj-C files and imported smooch.io framework.

Using Xcode 7.3, what can be the problem?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this, please? I have the same problem now (albeit with a different pod).

Comment: I did. Then this happened again and I forgot how :/ I'll post here when I figure it out again

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your podfile, you should include the framework thats causing problems inside the AppTests as well.

```
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
end

target 'MyAppTests' do

 pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
end
```

After this:

- Clean
- Delete Derived Data

Comment: Thanks. In my case I'd missed the UI tests. My unit tests already had the correct settings.